# Where is Python's home directory?

Tags: python

I have Python 2.7 installed, Im looking at trying tensorflow and for windows it looks like it only works on python 3.5, I downloaded the python installer and it is apparently installed, but where?

Python 2.7 has a Python27 directory in C:, but I cant locate 3.5 anywhere.  I tried the installer again and it asked if I wanted to repair or remove.

EDIT: Im really trying to find pip3, which I assume is in the python35/scripts directory

Comment: Ok that worked thanks, not good with windows command line#

Comment: You don't really need to know the path if you have the Python Installer.  It is installed in C:\Windows which is already in the path, and `py -2.7 -m pip <pip_options>` will run pip for the specified version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Where is Python installed? or where is Python's HOME directory?*

An easy way to find where Python is installed, would be to do:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Which for me outputs:

```
C:\Users\Vallentin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

You can also use `sys.exec_prefix` which would be the equivalent of `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`.

If you then copy the directory part and paste it into Windows Explorer. Then it would take you to Python's home directory. You are then correct that pip would be located at.

```
C:\Users\Vallentin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip3.exe
```

---

From a command line this can also be done in a single line:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Alternatively you can also do:

- `which python` (Unix)
- `where python` (Windows)

---

*Where is a Python module installed?*

If you want to find where a Python module is located, then like `print(__file__)` the same can be done with modules:

```
import re
import flask

print(re.__file__)
print(flask.__file__)
```

Which for me outputs:

```
C:\Users\Vallentin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py
C:\Users\Vallentin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask-0.12-py3.6.egg\flask\__init__.py
```

Comment: OK yes its in that path, I expected it to be adjacent to Python27

Comment: For me that is indeed the case. If I go back to `Python` then there's multiply `Python*` directories for each version. But it of course all depends on where you installed it. `sys.executable` would be an easy way of finding that path.

Comment: I didnt do anything funky on install, just the recommended directory, anyway thats fine thanks

Comment: Didn't mean whether you did something funky. If I recall correctly, I've had Python 2.7 install somewhere else by default some years ago. The answer would also be a useful solution, no matter which OS your on.